# How can i display SQL data only if it contains a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

IM trying to

"Get the ID's of products ordered through any agent who takes at least one order from a customer in Kyoto, sorted by ID's from highest to lowest."

How would i write this in SQL? This is what i currently have

```
SELECT pid FROM orders

WHERE cid IN (

Select cid FROM customers
WHERE cid = 'c006'

);
```

Table: http://i.gyazo.com/dbe542fb2315d663c75c23e3ecfb74fd.png

Comment: provide the table schema.

Comment: provide schema of both tables customers and orders..

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I now have

Comment: @kid Done, please take a look now.

Comment: Please don't hide important information in images, not everyone can read them. It's preferred if you embed the table schema as text within the post itself.

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't know how to do that . Sorry, next time i'll be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
`SELECT pid FROM orders WHERE cid IN ( Select cid FROM customers
 WHERE cid.city == "Kyoto") order by pid DESC;`
```

In this case you dont need to explicitly mention the id of customer (c006).
There are several other methods also to do this using join [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) this post contains all the info needed..

```
SELECT pid FROM orders WHERE cid == "c006" order by pid;
```

that's it. whole query is to dig that cid where city == Kyoto.If I understood you correctly.

Comment: Your code don't work. This is my new code i tried to make.              SELECT pid      FROM orders
WHERE aid IN(

SELECT aid FROM orders
WHERE cid = 'c006'

) ORDER BY pid;

Comment: if you already know whats the cid of customer from kyoto then why dont you just query it from your orders table

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT o.pid FROM orders AS o INNER JOIN customers AS c ON o.pid = c.cid WHERE c.cid = "c006" ORDER BY p.pid DESC`

I'll suggest using inner join for this query.

Answer (score 0):

This may provide what you're looking for.  For this request:

> "Get the ID's of products ordered through any agent who takes at least
>   one order from a customer in Kyoto, sorted by ID's from highest to
>   lowest."

It appears that you want a list of products associated with a list of agents.  The agents must have at least one order from a customer in Kyoto.

```
SELECT pid
FROM Orders
WHERE aid IN
    (
    SELECT o.aid
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Customers c ON o.cid = c.cid
    WHERE c.city = 'Kyoto'
    )
ORDER BY pid
;
```

The sub-query returns a list of agent IDs that have at least one order with a customer from Kyoto.  The primary query returns the list of product IDs for the derived list of agents.

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/094c34/10)